# check hashed password and change it in php

Tags: php, hash, hashtable, login-control

This is my code, i want to update the password with the given new password `$new_password`, validate it with `$new_password2` and check if the current given password matches the `$old_password`.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //validations
    $required_fields = array("username", "old_password", "password",   "password2");
    validate_presences($required_fields);

    $fields_with_max_lengths = array("username" => 30);
    validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

    if(empty($errors)) {
      //process the form
      $id = $admin["id"];
      $username = mysql_prep($_POST["username"]);
      $new_password = password_encrypt($_POST["password"]);
      $old_password = password_encrypt($_POST["old_password"]);
      $new_password2 = password_encrypt($_POST["password2"]);
```

The two passwords you must give must be equal to each other to change the password. All three passwords are hashed. `$new_password` and `$new_password2` are needed to validate the new password. The `$old_password` must also be updated with the `$new_password`. It must be changed if the id equals the one in the database and if the `$old_password` matches the current `$old_password`.

```
      if ($new_password == $new_password2) {
        //update
        $query  = "UPDATE admins SET ";
        $query .= "username = '{$username}', ";
        $query .= "password = '{$new_password}', ";
        $query .= "old_password = '{$new_password}', ";
        $query .= "password2 = '{$new_password}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE id = {$id} ";
        $query .= "AND old_password = '{$old_password}' ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

      if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection) == 1) {
        //success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin updated.";
        redirect_to("manage_admins.php");

      } else {
        //failure
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin update failed1";
        }
      } else {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin update failed2";
      }
    } else {
      $_SESSION["message"] = "Admin update failed3";
    }
  } else {
      } 
?>
```

Comment: What issue are you running in to?

Comment: What is `password_encrypt`? Did you mean [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)?

Comment: It tells me i have an error if($new_password == $new_password2){ }

Comment: yes, password_encrypt is to hash the posted credentials in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You may have meant password_hash instead of password_encrypt.  Still, this would be the wrong usage.  Look into [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).  The basic idea is that you get the current hashed password for that user from the DB and then use password_verify to check the user entry against the stored hash.

Comment: I do not know really, i have form in html which i send credentials in. Those credentials will be encrypted in the database. These are three values, in this code i am trying to check if the old_password matches the hashed one, later i add a new hashed one and have to verify the new one. Sorry for the indistinctness

Comment: Password_verify is this:   function password_encrypt($password) {
    $hash_format = "$2y$10$";
    $salt_length = 22;
    $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
    return $hash;
  }